# SQL Server : splitting a row into multiple rows from OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, output

I am trying to get a query that can help me achieve something similar to the image below:

[image: Output result set]

The first table is the result of a SQL `OUTPUT` clause (both inserted and deleted). I would like to split these results into a new table (like the second one in the above image). So I want to have one row depicting the inserted records and the second row depicting the deleted records.

This is how my sample data was created:

```
select 
    inserted_ID = 1,
    inserted_name = 'Brian',
    inserted_phone = '123-456-7890',
    operation_type1 = 'inserted',
    deleted_id = 2,
    deleted_name = 'James',
    deleted_phone = '222-222-2222',
    operation_type2 = 'Deleted'
into 
    #tbltest
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why do you have a table structure like this in the first place? It seems "odd" to have `Inserted_ID` and `Deleted_ID` on the same row. Is there any actual / natural relationship between those two?

Comment: Hi @srutzky. This is really just an example. It's not a real table in my database. Also, when using the OUTPUT clause with an UPDATE statement, SQL Server allows us to show both the inserted record and the deleted record.

Comment: @Solution Yes, the `OUTPUT` clause allows access to both `inserted` and `deleted` records during an `UPDATE` statement, which is exactly what I stated in my answer. BUT, even if you access both `inserted` and `deleted` values, per each row coming out of `OUTPUT`, `inserted` and `deleted` represent the _same_ row: `inserted` is the "current" value of each column, and `deleted" is the "old" value of each column. But they will never be different rows. Hence this separation that you are asking for only makes sense if wanting "before" and "after" versions of a row to be in diff rows in your table.

Comment: Also, it would help to know what you are actually trying to accomplish with this. It could be that there is a better method that is not being presented because you were too specific in describing the problem with your implementation, rather than the original problem that lead you to your implementation. For example, if you are wanting to audit modifications to a table, a Trigger would be easier and better than all of this extra code that needs to be replicated per each DML statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try to organize your table structure something like (keep attention on [uid]):

```
create table [my_table]
(
     [id]       int
    ,[name]     nvarchar(256)
    ,[phone]    nvarchar(256)
); 

insert into [my_table] 
values (1, 'Brian', '123-456-7890');

create table [my_log]
(
     [inserted_id]      int
    ,[inserted_name]    nvarchar(256)
    ,[inserted_phone]   nvarchar(256)
    ,[deleted_id]       int
    ,[deleted_name]     nvarchar(256)
    ,[deleted_phone]    nvarchar(256)   
    ,[uid]              uniqueidentifier primary key    
);
```

And then this solves your problem:

```
update [my_table]
set [id]     = 2        
    ,[name]  = 'James'
    ,[phone] = '222-222-2222'
output
     [deleted].[id]
    ,[deleted].[name]
    ,[deleted].[phone]
    ,[inserted].[id]
    ,[inserted].[name]
    ,[inserted].[phone] 
    ,newid()
into [my_log]
(
     [inserted_id]
    ,[inserted_name]
    ,[inserted_phone]   
    ,[deleted_id]
    ,[deleted_name]
    ,[deleted_phone]    
    ,[uid]
);

select
     [id]       =   [id]
    ,[name]     =   [name]
    ,[phone]    =   [phone]
    ,[op_type]  =   CASE [op_type] WHEN 0 THEN 'Insert' ELSE 'Delete' END
from    
    ( 
        select 
             [id]       =   [inserted_id]
            ,[name]     =   [inserted_name]
            ,[phone]    =   [inserted_phone]
            ,[op_type]  =   0   --  insert
            ,[uid]      =   [uid]
        from 
            [my_log] 
        union
        select 
             [id]       =   [deleted_id]
            ,[name]     =   [deleted_name]
            ,[phone]    =   [deleted_phone]
            ,[op_type]  =   1   --  delete
            ,[uid]      =   [uid]
        from 
            [my_log]
    ) as [l]
order by 
     [l].[uid] 
    ,[l].[op_type]  ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks @Juozas, this is a more elaborate answer and it worked just fine. I am unable to mark as answer because I am new to quora so it won't allow me. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for a interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you are using the `MERGE` statement, you cannot both `INSERT` and `DELETE` in the same DML operation. The only time (outside of `MERGE`) that you will have rows in both the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables is during an `UPDATE` operation, and in that case, the rows in both will refer to the same actual rows in the tables, just the before and after views of those rows. Meaning, you won't see values like are what is being shown in the question where `Inserted_ID` and `Deleted_ID` differ.
2. If you are using `MERGE`, then you should already have the rows in the desired format since one row from the `OUTPUT` clause wouldn't represent multiple rows being affected. Meaning: `OUTPUT` already works are you are wanting it to, not as you are stating that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OUTER / CROSS APPLY operator:

```
select ...
from #Output / @Output as o
cross apply (
    select o.insertedColA, o.insertedColB, 'I'
    -- where o.insertedID is not null
    union all
    select o.deletedColB, ..., 'D'
    -- where o.deletedID is not null
) as x(ColA, ColB, RowType)
```